# Splunk: Entry looks like an array but can't be accessed as one

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I've got a portion of a log entry which looks like an array, but I can only access it with the `{}` notation.

For example, I think the path is `line.ul-log-data.meta.data[0].foo`, but the only way I can access the value is `line.ul-log-data.meta.data{}.foo`.

I've been experimenting with various multivalue field evaluations but coming up short. For example, when I do an `mvcount("line.ul-log-data.meta.data")`, it returns `1`.

What do I have to do to use the array notation `[0]` and get that count to return `2`?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Splunk doesn't [directly] have the concept of an "array". It has multivalue fields that are accessed with `mvindex` in an `eval` or `where` (or similar) statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splunk uses curly brackets to access JSON arrays because square brackets have a very different, historical function.

Have you tried `mvcount("line.ul-log-data.meta.data{}")`?

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks, yes, I have - `line.ul-log-data.meta.data{}.foo`, for example.  I'm curious how to explicitly path to that second index in that `{}` chunk.  Also, what is the historical function you're referring to? Would love to dig into some keywords there.

Comment: Square brackets define a subsearch, which doesn't apply here.
Accessing a specific array entry is very non-intuitive.  Aside from needing curly braces, we also need to use the `mvindex` function.  `| eval foo=mvindex('line.ul-log-data.meta.data{}', 1)`.  To count array elements, use the `mvcount` function.  `| eval count=mvcount('line.ul-log-data.meta.data{}')`.  Note the use of single quotes in both examples.